# Why gets() takes more character

Tags: c++, c

Here is my code

```
char c[3];
gets(c);
puts(c);
```

here char variable c have 3 index. But if I type more than 3 letter then my code print more than than 3 letter exactly which I type.
But how can it possible c can store only 3 character at a time. Isn't it?

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: UB ! n read about buffer overflow bug in gets..

Answer (score 5):

From the notes for [`gets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets):

> The function provides no means to prevent buffer overflow of the destination array, given sufficiently long input string.

So if `stdin` happens to have more than 3 characters, your code is just undefined behavior. This is a good reason to prefer calling:

```
fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
```

which definitely won't overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the wonderful world of [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

There is no length checking on the array, so the code walks off the end of the array and keeps writing into the adjacent memory. This is one of the many causes of security issues in code.

Answer (score 2):

`gets()` doesn't limit the nunmber of characters to read and it doesn't care where it is going to write them, it assumes that the destination buffer is big enough.

Why would you expect it to stop reading?

And precisely because of that, you should use a differet function to limit the number of characters to read, you need `fgets()`

```
char c[3];

fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
puts(c);
```

this will work without problem, note however, that only 2 characthers will be actually read, because the 3rd position is saved for the terminating `'\0'` byte, which makes your array a string.

Your program is invoking undefined behavior, so you might observe wierd results or your program could work normally, it does not depend on the program itself but on other things, for example on the input, and other things too.

Answer (score 1):

It's your responsibility to ensure that your buffer is large enough to hold the entire string read by `gets()` (including the terminating null). If you fail to do so, undefined behaviour occurs (which in practice means other memory locations are overwritten). This cannot be done safely in general unless you have guarantees about the length of the input string. That's why `gets` was deprecated in C99 and C++11 and removed in C11 and C++14. Consider using `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`gets()` doesn't actually know how big the block of memory passed to it is. If you give it more chars than the block size, you're invoking undefined behavior.